# When SF CRM field is updated, Subscriber Status is MC has to be updated as 'Active'. Is this possible to do this with http callout in flow in CRM?

Tags: httprequest

In Salesforce CRM 'opt in__c' custom field is updated as 'True', I need to update that subscriber's  status in SF Marketing cloud as 'Active'.

We can do this with apex code and soap api.

Can it be achieved with http callout action in flow in CRM?

Created
1.Record Triggered Flow to get the records whose optin field value is true.
2.This flow is calling 'Auto Launched flow'
3.In Auto Launched flow adding http callout action.
4.Selecting Endpoint URL - https://"Sub-domain from MC".rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/contacts/SubscriberKey/subscriptions

Is this endpoint url correct?

Can anybody help me with request body and response to give in http callout action in flow?